# How to handle huge translation tables in Angular2

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation, ng2-translate

It seems i18n is still neglected in Angular2. I've been expecting that someone came up with translation files per `component` like you could reference `styleUrl`s for CSS. That doesn't seem to be planned right now. It would also be giant leap forward if ngx-translate would support multiple files for the same languages in order to give it a little structure, at least, which is still an [open issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/271) for over 4 months. Of course, ngx-translate supports `nested` keys which is good but not sufficient.

Is there a (de facto) way to use multiple translation files? How do you handle thousands of key/value pairs?

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to (ab)use one app per component, so they have their own translation files.

Comment: You mean to configure the TranslateModule for every Angular module with its particular subset of components? Could be a solution. I'm just reading up on custom Decorators.